# Compiled Query error: there is no implicit conversion from entities to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-4

I'm creating a delegate to retrieve all customers records from database. I have used compiled query in this way , but for some reason I'm getting an error like this in Visual studio 2012 with EF.

> Error: The type 'HTML5Basics.NorthwindDataContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TArg0' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.Compile(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'HTML5Basics.NorthwindDataContext' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'.

What is this error and how to solve this error?

Here is code:

```
public static Func<NorthwindDataContext, string, IEnumerable<SimpleCustomer>> CustomersByCity =
            CompiledQuery.Compile<NorthwindDataContext, string, IEnumerable<SimpleCustomer>>(
            (NorthwindDataContext db, string city) =>
            from c in db.Customers
            where c.City == city
            select new SimpleCustomer { ContactName = c.ContactName });
```

Comment: You need to include your code that's throwing the exception.

Comment: i have added code which gives erros

Answer (score 1):

> There is no implicit reference conversion from 'HTML5Basics.NorthwindDataContext' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'.

Indicates there is no conversion between the two types.

In .NET 4.5, EF5 there is a System.Data.Objects namespace which contains CompiledQuery.Compile function.
There is also one in the System.Data.Linq namespace.

They have a different signature:

System.Data.Linq Namespace:
(taken from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548737.aspx):

```
public static Func<TArg0, TResult> Compile<TArg0, TResult>(
Expression<Func<TArg0, TResult>> query)
where TArg0 : DataContext
```

System.Data.Objects Namespace (from .pdb):

```
public static Func<TArg0, TResult> Compile<TArg0, TResult> 
(Expression<Func<TArg0, TResult>> query) 
where TArg0 : ObjectContext
```

Basically you have 2 choices:

1) use the one in the System.Data.Linq namespace.

2) pass in an ObjectContext (or inherited type) into the System.Data.Objects namespace's version.